# Is there a way to show the full variable value in a console in Visual Studio Code during debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code while you are debugging you have a variables view that shows the variable name and the value. Sometimes the value is truncated. Is there a way to click on the value and show it in a console or the console? I've seen this in other editors.

FYI I know I can hover over the value and it is shown in a tool tip.

Answer (score 1):

With most debug adapters, you can just type the variable name into the [debug console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-console-repl):

[image]

The "Variables" panel also has a "Copy as Expression" in the context menu which can save you some typing.